# How do I configure an OpenGL makefile for Windows?(from Linux)

Tags: windows, linux, opengl, makefile

Here is the makefile:

```
CC      = g++
LD      = g++
CFLAGS  = -I/usr/X11R6/include -I. -c
LDFLAGS = -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lglut -lGLU -lGL -lXi -lXmu -lXt -lXext -lX11 -lSM -lICE -lm

INCS = 

OBJS = x.o

all: x

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJS) x

cgRender.o: $(INCS) x.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) x.cpp -o x.o

cgRender: $(OBJS)
    $(LD) $(OBJS) -o x $(LDFLAGS)
```

Its made for Linux but I'm trying to compile it on windows.

The errors I keep getting look like this:

```
c:/strawberry/c/bin/*directories that don't exist/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lGlu/-lGl/-lXi/etc....
```

If somebody could help me out here, I'd be very appreciative. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> LDFLAGS = -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lglut -lGLU -lGL -lXi -lXmu -lXt -lXext -lX11 -lSM -lICE -lm

In Windows you normaly don't link against X11 libraries, so remove all the `-lX…`, `-lSM` and `-lICE`. Also remove the X11 include and library directory parameters `-I/usr/X11R6/include`, `-L/usr/X11R6/lib`.

Note that this Makefile must be really old, because neither those libraries, nor the directories should require explicit mentioning to the compiler or linker, as GLUT pulls the libraries as dynamic library dependency.

Comment: Wouldn't the inclusion of those libraries mean that functions from them are referenced in the code, implying that not only the makefile, but also the code requires porting to a Windows environment?

Comment: @eriktous: If the code the OP tries to compile stuck to using GLUT then it should be portable. The references to that libraries are probably there, because linkers used to be inable to pull the dependencies from the linked SO imports and had to be fed explicitly. These days this is no longer neccessary on most systems.